# Navigating using XPath stored as a string

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to store XPath of an XML attribute as a string in a separate file so that if XPath changes, I can easily modify the navigation to the attribute without changing code.

For example, in following XML:

```
<Result>
  <Server = "main">
    <Client id="1"></Client>
  </Server>
</Result>
```

if I want to navigate to id attribute of Client element, I can have following string:

> Result->Server->Client->id

I am not sure how in C# I can navigate using this string form of XPath and then, read the attribute value from the target XML.

Please help.
Harit

Comment: that is not valid xml `<Server = "main">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly, your XML is a bit strange, with

```
<Server = "main">
```

Do you mean

```
<Server id="main">
```

But, regardless of that, you could just store the XPath directly instead of your string version. Like:

```
/Result/Server/Client[0]/@id
```

then you read the string from the file and pass it into something like:

```
public string GetClientIdString(string xPathString)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("SomeXml.xml");
    return doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPathString).Value;
}
```

The issue becomes that you can't really store the XPath exactly how you would like if you plan on having more than one Client under Server. If you need that functionality, though, you could parse out your version of the XPath and do something like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetClientIdStrings(string elementXPath, string attribute)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(SomeXml.xml);
    var clientIdStrings = new List<string>();

    foreach(var node in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(elementXPath))
    {
        clientIdStrings.Add(node.Attributes[attribute].Value);
    }

    return clientIdStrings;
}
```